# bootstrap a-tag doesn`t work on tablet and smartphone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I encountered a problem with the a-tag on a recent project: The Link works fine in the Desktop Version, as soon as I scale down the browser to md or sm the link doesnt work anymore. Now this is really strange because I ve never changed anything.

```html
   <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
           <h2>Lorem Ipsum:</h2>
               <p>Dolor Sit amet</p>
               <a href="#works"> <i class="fa fa-toggle-right"></i> LINK</a>
    <br></div>
```

Regarding the link: Doesn`t matter wether I link to an ID, file or external link, always the same...

Does anyone know how, or where I could have made a mistake? As the classes only link to the main bootstrap file I really cant find whats wrong. Regarding possible javaScripts or JQuery scripts which could interfer: I checked and the error only occurs on some pages, other links work fine, eventhough the same scripts are running...

Comment: no such issue! the link is working in all viewports

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly it isnt... Heres the project Im having the error with: http://webdesign-basel.com/nothelfer.html. I really cant find any errors either, but it still isnt working...

Comment: can you tell me, where shall i exactly look for error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, whenever you use Bootstrap framework, remember that, while defining columns, you also need to define columns for lowest viewport, otherwise, float issue arises, and you don't get height of its child elements.
This is how the CSS for bootstrap has been written.

So for best practice:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
 your content.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! I`ll keep that in mind, sadly I wasn`t aware of that.

Comment: no, not your fault! many people aren't aware of that! but while inspecting the code, if you check for multiple view-ports, you'll notice such issue

Answer (score 1):

Please use this in CSS. Actually this issue raised by overlapping div named as '.col-sm-8'. Use below code only for mobile view-port.

```
.col-sm-8 {clear:both;}
```